# PIE rounded corners won't work

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, rounded-corners, css3pie

Hey guys I'm building a website and found out ie8 wouldnt work with rounded corners. After a bit of research I found out that PIE would tackle this problem, and yes it did, but it also screws the complete site over. The divs are scrolling away and the image's ignore the rounded corners :(, anyone that can help. The problem is a bit difficult to discribe so here's the link http://www.k2stuc.nl Hope someone can help me out with getting it compatible with ie8.

Comment: I'm all in favour of CSS3Pie; it's a good little hack. But in truth, it's not always really necessary. How much would IE8 users miss having the rounded corners? Does it affect their ability to use and enjoy the site? Could you just leave it and let them have square corners? Would it be that bad really?

Comment: Have you read through the CSS3Pie documentation. There's a list of common issues that people have with it, and explainations of how to solve them. It's a near certainty that your issues are covered in there.

Comment: Yeah I have read the documentation, the problem is my client want's it really bad :( it's some weird div scrolling :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `relative` positioning to container of PIE element.

```
.column{position:relative;}
```

Also in some cases you may need to use `zoom:1` property.

Comment: Do I have to add it to the .column or to the .rc pseudo class?

Comment: you can add it directly to .column. It will be OK.

Comment: Also you need add border-radius to images at the bottom of each column. Now it looks not very good. (:

Comment: yes that fixed one of the problems, the other problem I encounterd was images that are in the divs with round corners wont get round corners and get on top of the round corner div

Comment: Wich class do you mean by the images?

Comment: with PIE you can't use {overflow:hidden;} to element with CSS3 properties. In your case, you should use {border-radius:15px;} to div.image.rc and to image inside this div.

Comment: So I dont have to add the behavior? only the border-radius: 10px;?

Comment: No. You need to add behavior to both elements, div.image.rc and to image inside it. Also you need to add .image.rc img{border-radius:10px;}

Comment: I think I have fixed it, let me check